# set up global variables dynamically in gitlab-ci

Tags: global-variables, gitlab-ci

I want to set some variables by getting the values from a pom.xml file. These variables need to be global because they will be used in multiple stages and jobs.

According to the gitlab-ci documentation, I can set global variables in two differents ways:

1. using a variable statement:

   ```
   variable:  
    pom_artifactID: $(grep -m1 '<artifactId>' pom.xml | cut -d '<' -f2  |cut -d '>' -f2)
   ```
2. Using a "before" script:

   ```
    before_script:
      - pom_artifactID=$(grep -m1 '<artifactId>' pom.xml | cut -d '<' -f2  |cut -d '>' -f2)
      - pom_artifactVersion=$(grep -m1 '<version>' pom.xml | cut -d '<' -f2  |cut -d '>' -f2)
      - pom_packaging=$(grep -m1 '<packaging>' pom.xml | cut -d '<' -f2  |cut -d '>' -f2)
      - pom_finalName=$({ grep -m1 '<finalName>' pom.xml |  cut -d '<' -f2 | cut -d '>' -f2; [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ] && true || echo ${pom_artifactID}-${pom_artifactVersion}.$pom_packaging}; })
   ```

The first doesn't work because gitlab-ci doesn't evaluate $(command), so `pom_artifactID` becomes a literal "$(grep -m1 '' pom.xml | cut -d '<' -f2  |cut -d '>' -f2)"

The second doesn't work either because "before_script" relies on the "grep" command and some docker images used in my pipeline have an old version of grep.

There is another way to set global variables o pass variables between stages and jobs?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Passing values between jobs and stages

There is currently no way in GitLab to pass environment variable between stages or jobs.
But there is a request for that: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22638

Current workaround is to use **artifacts** - basically pass files.
We had a similar use case - get Java app version from `pom.xml` and pass it to various jobs later in the pipeline.

How we did it in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - package

variables:
  VARIABLES_FILE: ./variables.txt  # "." is required for image that have sh not bash

get-version:
  stage: build
  script:
    - APP_VERSION=... # $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - echo "export APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION" > $VARIABLES_FILE
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $VARIABLES_FILE
package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - source $VARIABLES_FILE
    - echo "Use env var APP_VERSION here as you like ..."
```

### Extracting values from `pom.xml`

By the way it's better to treat `xml.pom` as XML to extract values from `pom.xml` rather than plain `grep`, because XML elements can potentially span multiple lines.

There are at least a couple of options, examples:

1. Use XPath in `xmllint` tool from `libxml2-utils`

```
get-version:
  image: ubuntu
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y libxml2-utils
    - APP_VERSION=`xmllint --xpath '/*[local-name()="project"]/*[local-name()="version"]/text()' $POM_FILE`
```

2. Use `python` xml processing

```
get-version:
  image: python3
  script:
    - APP_VERSION=$(python3 -c "import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET; print(ET.parse(open('pom.xml')).getroot().find('{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version').text)")
```

Comment: Extracting values from `pom.xml` can also be achieved using _mvn_ command itself with a little help from the _maven-help-plugin_, i. e. `APP_VERSION=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)`.

Answer (score 5):

There is another option that I have used as well. You can setup variables in the CI/CD settings, then from within a job issue a PUT back to the API to set them to a value you want to share across jobs.

```
script:
- >- 
  curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_PROJ_TOKEN" 
  "https://someinstance.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/variables/MY_VARIABLE"
  --form "value=0"
```

In the above example it is calling a custom instance of gitlab, I also have a project access token defined in the project as GITLAB_PROJ_TOKEN. My variable name is MY_VARIABLE.

Answer (score 2):

Since gitlab 13.0, is possible to save the variables in a [dotenv file format](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) that is loaded in other stages.

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_VARIABLE=value_from_build_job" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "$BUILD_VARIABLE"  # Output is: 'value_from_build_job'
```

Still very similar to the accepted answer but now is not necessary explicitly load the file with the variables before a new stage/job starts but if you want you can use `needs` or `dependencies` keywords to do so.