# How to store grep command that in Variables section in script variable (gitlab.ci)?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want my job to execute grep command that in variable in Variables section.

I have this gitlabci.yml:

```
variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: "grep -m1 '<artifactId>' pom.xml | grep -oP '(?<=>).*(?=<)'"
    
sample-job:
  script:
  - |
    var=? <-- here I want to store the result of the grep of "PROJECT_NAME"
```

I tried before:

```
var=${PROJECT_NAME} OR $(PROJECT_NAME)
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to store it into the current shell/job, or multiple jobs in your pipeline?

Comment: @evelynhathaway I want to reuse the PROJECT_NAME as Global variable for the next jobs, deploys scripts.
When I putted the grep in the script it worked but this will bring duplicate code :(

Comment: You would have to either reuse the grep command in every job that needs that name in your script or use artifacts to pass a `.env` file between jobs. Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674733/2758250

Comment: @evelynhathaway did you try to use `eval` ? See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949)

Comment: @NicolasPepinster that is one way to reuse the script as a GitLab variable, I was specifically commenting on the reusability of shell variables between pipeline jobs

Comment: I suppose another way would be a dynamic child pipeline. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines In the generative stage, you create the yaml that the generated pipeline then uses. So when generating the yaml you could do your evaluations and set the var there. In the generated yaml it will look hard coded.