# Why is Gitlab CICD workflow:rules:if:variables failing to set variables?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

```yaml
stages:
  - test

# Default vars
variables:
  DEPLOY_VARIABLE: "dev-deploy"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      variables:
        DEPLOY_VARIABLE: "master-deploy"  # Override globally-defined DEPLOY_VARIABLE

my_project_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - env | grep CI
    - echo $DEPLOY_VARIABLE // this always outputs dev-deploy.
```

Running with gitlab-runner 14.10.1.

No matter if i try that locally or on Gitlab that var is never set.

On local I run it with `gitlab-runner exec shell my_project_test`.

`env | grep CI` is:

```
CI_SERVER_VERSION=
CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH=darwin/amd64
CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=master
CI_JOB_TOKEN=
CI_PROJECT_ID=0
CI_RUNNER_REVISION=f761588f
... etc
```

As per their documentation:
If a rule matches, when: always is the default, and when: never is the default if nothing matches.

I even tried `if: '1 == 1'` and so on.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. I used an equivalent YAML to what you posted and the [job on my public project on gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/spyoungtech/testproject/-/jobs/2481752623#L110) works as expected. Maybe you have this variable set in your CI/CD project or group settings? Settings will take precedence over anything in the YAML.

Comment: I don't have any vars in CI/CD or group settings.

Comment: I just tried your project on local with `gitlab-runner exec shell my_project_test` and again I get dev-deploy // this always outputs dev-deploy. @sytech

Comment: Using `gitlab-runner exec shell` is not a valid test because it does not evaluate `workflow:rules:`

Comment: Potentially relevant bug: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/341091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitlab-runner exec` has [several limitations](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec) and does not implement/consider many features of YAML definitions, including `workflow:rules:[]variables` in this case.

However, [when run through gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/spyoungtech/testproject/-/jobs/2481752623#L110) or a self-hosted instance of GitLab, `workflow:rules:` will evaluate properly.

Keep in mind, there are a few cases where variables set elsewhere will [take precedence](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence) over variables defined in the YAML, such as when variables are set in project, group, or instance settings.

Answer (score 0):

the assignment should works if you put the condition in your task.

```
my_project_test:
  stage: test
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
       variables:
        DEPLOY_VARIABLE: "master-deploy"  # Override globally-defined DEPLOY_VARIABLE
  script:
    - env | grep CI
    - echo $DEPLOY_VARIABLE // this always outputs dev-deploy.
```

However the variable is only in the scope of your job, which is under your if condition, it won't overwrite the global value in the another job.

What you really need to pass variable between jobs :

[set up global variables dynamically in gitlab-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672150/set-up-global-variables-dynamically-in-gitlab-ci)

Comment: That means I have to copy same code into 10 steps of a build. I need global variables and then override them if it is a marge req or push and so on.